# JQuery AJAX return XML on GET request complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to execute code once my XML file (or object) has been returned successfully. Not before, and not repeatedly; just one time **after** the file has been returned.

Does my code already do what I am trying to accomplish? It seems to have failed a couple of times in IE and I need to be sure that it is reliable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function GetFile(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "Produce.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
                alert("XML File is loaded!");
                alert(result);
                },      
            async: true
          });
    })();
});
```

I know that there are `onerror` codes and `readystatechange` values that can be checked and verified... Should I be checking these values while polling the server for the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove comma after `async: true`

Also, your GetFile function will execute immediately if you're not planning on calling again then might as well go with anonymous or remove that function all together

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "Produce.xml",
          dataType: "xml",
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
                alert("XML File is loaded!");
                alert(result);
                },      
            async: true
          });
});
```

Comment: Ooops typo; had some extra code in there before I pasted it in.

Comment: It seems that even though I tell it to execute my function on success, from time to time it does not. In my "real" coded version it will skip the function in Success; could this be due to an error? It simply seems unreliable and I am hoping to make it more robust.

Comment: You should also include an error handler. It's either success or error if it skipped success then it would have just exited since there is no error callback.

Comment: Added the following code `error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError);},` and waiting for it to trigger. Should I reinvoke the "GetFile" function on fail and perhaps use a timeout with a counter? I'll give it a go.

Comment: I edited my main code to reflect some changes, however it appears that it must be "peer reviewed" first. Perhaps I'm asking too many questions! I added the following line to my `error:function` - `setTimeout(GetFile (), 5000);` But it is still looping inifinitely. I also tried `setInterval` but that made no difference.

Comment: DOH I edited your code instead of mine! Sorry! But I'm giving you credit for the answer. So thanks a lot! I just jad to change `setTimeout(GetFile (), 5000);` to `setTimeout(GetFile, 5000);` and it works. Not quite sure why that is, but I'm still learning.

Comment: setTimeout accepts a function reference. GetFile but you actually invoked a function GetFile(). Anyway glad it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This was added as an edit by the original asker, I have converted it to a community wiki answer because it should be an answer, not an edit.</sub>

Fixed it thanks to @AndrewDouglas suggestion and here is the new code (which works great):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function GetFile(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "Produce.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
            alert("XML File is loaded!");
            alert(result);
        },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            z++;
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
            setTimeout(GetFile, 5000);
            console.log("Error " +z+": " + thrownError);
        },              
            async: true
        });
    })();
});
```

One final comment, you should be able to change `setTimeout(GetFile, 5000)` to `setInterval(GetFile, 5000)` and then it will continually poll your XML file. Doing that in the `success` section would make a bit more sense, however.