# UI5: Changing from JSON to XML Model -> missing oValue

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, data-binding, rss, sapui5

Main Question: I try since 4 days to make Data Binding Work so I made the Program very easy because I thought with a easy MVC it's easy to change from JSON to XML (actualy I want to use RSS Feed as Model later).

So I analyzed console logs and tried everything I found on the official site as well as on Stackoverflow, but I still miss something.

so for the start I have this view:

```
<core:View 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    controllerName="paketnameAdresse.controller.button">

    <Panel text="Hello World">
        <Button text="{/text}" press="doSomething"/>
    </Panel>

</core:View>
```

and this JSON:
`{"text": "Say Hello"}`

and this controller :

```
sap.ui.controller("paketnameAdresse.controller.button", {

    onInit : function () { //lädt Model
        var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("paketnameAdresse", "/data.json");
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sPath);
    },

    doSomething: function () {
        sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("nav", "to", {
            id : "iconGroup"
        });
    }

});
```

and then i tried everything with XML like:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
oModel.setXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><text>data</text>");
oModel.setData("data.xml");
oModel.loadData("data.xml");
```

with the following XML:

Say Hello

In the Document data.xml as well in the controller

Where did I go wrong?

PS: Side Questions:

What I do have to know about RSS? Do things change?
How I get XML / RSS via HTTP get/via URL?
When it comes to update Methods, is it best to use a POST Method? 
If No, which Method is best?

PSS: 
console logs:

**JSON:**

[image: JSON Console Screenshot]

oValue: "Say Hello"

sInternalType: "string"

sMode: "TwoWay"

**XML**

[image: XML Console Screeenshot]

oValue: ""

sInternalType: "string"

sMode: "TwoWay"

Comment: Where do you make the model available to the view?

Comment: looks like he has direct binding in UI. {/text} will actually make call
<hostname><port>/oServiceUrl/text
I don't think text is one of the OData collection.

Comment: it had to do with the Binding i made a coment below your post.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Binding looks wrong.. You are trying to bind a collection to the `Button`

Correct way: `<Button text="{text}" press="doSomething"/>`

```
onInit : function () { 
        var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("paketnameAdresse", "/data.json");
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sPath);
       // you have to bind this to view
       this.getView().setModel(oModel)
    },
```

Your **XML** binding looks fine.

---

**How to get data using URL?**
Use `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.read(sPath, mParameters?)`: object
Trigger a GET request to the odata service that was specified in the model constructor. The data will not be stored in the model. The requested data is returned with the response.

**To Update?**
Use `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.update(sPath, mParameters?) : object`
Trigger a PUT/MERGE request to the odata service that was specified in the model constructor. Please note that deep updates are not supported and may not work. These should be done separate on the entry directly.

Read More here about [sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html) to know about parameters and the thier types.
It's also recommended to use [`ODataModel v2`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html).

If you want use just `jQuery` AJAX [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988780/jquery-ajax-return-xml-on-get-request-complete).
I don't know about **RSS** feeds. May be someone will answer that part

**UPDATE:** Sample way to use: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/connecttobn/SAPUI5Examples/blob/master/ODataBindingExample.html)

Comment: first thing is someone helped me and then i came to this:  {text} wont work, but if i add some root element in the Xml Model {/text} works (finaly). Maybe because i use .model.xml.XMLModel instead of .model.json.JSONModel?

The other things i will test, but i need some time, i wright back later.

Comment: i just tried to use sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.read but then i asked myself"ive never used that, how i have to use that?" can you give me an example?